# convert a class file to a applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a java class which running perfectly but now I need to run this class as a web application so I need to convert this class to an applet how can I convert this class to an applet.
I know little bid about applet like it's life cycle 
init()

start()

paint()

stop()

destroy()

and to run a applet 
**applet code = "LifeTest.class"**

so any one help me to convert this class to an applet and if it is not possible then any suggestion as a substitute

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 8000;



public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);

/**
 * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
 * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
 * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
 * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
 */

byte[] receiveData = new byte[5000];

format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

while (status == true) {
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
            receiveData.length);

    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

    ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            receivePacket.getData());

    ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
    toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());

}



}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
try {

    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

    sourceDataLine.open(format);

    FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    volumeControl.setValue(6.0206f);

    sourceDataLine.start();
    sourceDataLine.open(format);

    sourceDataLine.start();

    System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

    sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
    System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
    sourceDataLine.drain();
    sourceDataLine.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `Applet`. Let me give you sample code for it.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

Create `MANIFEST.MF` file using some text editor. Place it in same directory where your `.java` file is. Its content should be like.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: Name of your application
```

Now you need to compile your code and need to attach `MANIFEST.MF` file in it.

```
javac HelloWorld.java
jar cvfm MANIFEST.MF HelloWorld.jar *.class
```

Now create one `.html` file and place `<applet>` tag in it.

```
<applet name="HelloWorld" code="HelloWorld.class"
        archive="HelloWorld.jar" width="100" height="100">          
</applet>
```

Comment: thanks vicky can u please give me one small project where all of those file like .MF .java .html

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuit.zip open `index.html` after extracting zip file. online: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ .You can also open `circuit.jar` file in rar/zip software

Comment: still now not able to covert that